# Why the breathing in Snowgoons Get Off the Ground

Tags: song-lyrics

At around 3:10 in Snowgoons Get Off the Ground (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yih_bMc5B7o), Ruste Juxx starts rapping. Why is his portion accompanied by heavy breathing?

Here are the associated lyrics (taken from genius: https://genius.com/Snowgoons-get-off-the-ground-lyrics)

> Machine gun skunk I blow dolo
>   That's why your bitch jocked me like Polo
>   I ain't gotta go get it cause I got it on me
>   I smell like palm trees, nothing but exotic on me
>   Hoes get erotic on me, I put the pipe down
>   Stick the pipe in her mouth tell her pipe down
>   Now lick a shot for niggas doing life inside
>   Grabbing you by the neck, sticking the knife inside
>   It's B-R-double-O-K, double A-K brining trouble your way
>   Knock niggas out, they can't get off the ground
>   Shell cases found, the cops get off the ground
>   So put a muzzle on that bi-suiter rap shit
>   Nigga knuckle up, cock rugers back bitch
>   Ruste Juxx bullets blow out your brain
>   Think it's a game, listen to Lil' Fame

Comment: Not sure I follow - are you asking about the music itself, or the lyrics? How do you think that that changes the interpretation?

Comment: Could you post the lyrics associated with the heavy breathing?  There might be some association...  (Note: there is a precedent for breathing as literature.  One of Samuel Beckett's famous short plays consists of no words, but only a cry and a breath: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breath_(play) ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the performance of a piece of music, and not about literature (including song lyrics) as such.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the lyrics (supplied via an edit, but pending approval)

- I'd say the use of breathing has double meaning, indicating the convolution of sex and death

The Death Drive is a concept deriving from Freudian theory, proposed by Sabina Spielrein in her paper "Destruction as the Cause of Coming Into Being".  From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_drive):

> "The death drive opposes Eros, the tendency toward survival, propagation, sex, and other creative, life-producing drives."

The full text Dr. Spielrein's paper [can be found here](https://www.arizonapsychoanalyticsociety.com/downloads/sabrina.pdf). [*Journal of Analytical Psychology*, 1994]

At a very high level, it has to do with a desire to re-enact traumas, and the idea that erotic, as well as violent, inclinations can originate in trauma.

The lyrics are almost a textbook example of the conflation of violence and eroticism:

> Hoes get erotic on me, I put the pipe down  
>   Stick the pipe in her mouth tell her pipe down 
>   Now lick a shot for niggas doing life inside  
>   Grabbing you by the neck, sticking the knife inside 
>   
> <sub>SOURCE: [Metrolyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/get-off-the-ground-lyrics-snowgoons.html)</sub>

Note that double meanings are heavily utilized: "pipe" initially means weed pipe but subsequently the male sexual organ; "lick a shot" uses firearms vocabulary in conjunction with ejaculation; "grabbing you by the neck" in this context refers not only to murder by strangulation, but [erotic asphyxiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erotic_asphyxiation); "knife" refers both to a stabbing weapon and the male sexual organ.

- the breathing sounds indicate excitement, which could be erotic, set against the [crunky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crunk) (dark) production and violent imagery of the lyrics

---

See Also: [Oprah, Carl Jung, and a Remarkable Essay about Sex and Death](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-bejeezus-out-me/201407/oprah-carl-jung-and-remarkable-essay-about-sex-and-death)